# Exception thrown, Dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c, exception, memory, dynamic, allocation

Hi I'm trying to do dynamic memory allocation of a large matrix in C but I'm running into the following error:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF63A248571 in cdempd.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000. occurred

sometimes it's Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFB412E2A0.

```
double ndivx, ndivy, ndivz, nt, r, box, dx, totnode;




int main()
{


    ndivx = 19.0;
    ndivy = 19.0;
    ndivz = 19.0;
    int totnode = ndivx * ndivy * ndivz;
    r = 0.005;  //diameter of sphere
    dx = 0.0025 / ndivx;
    double dx = r / ndivx; // distance between points



    int cols = 3;

    int** coords;
    coords = malloc(totnode * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < totnode; i++) {
        coords[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int));

    }


    //int* coord = (int*)malloc(totnode * cols * sizeof(int));


    //  int offset = i * cols + j;
    // now mat[offset] corresponds to m(i, j)
    //create a cube of equidistant points

    int numm = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= ndivx; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= ndivy; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= ndivz; k++)
            {

                coords[numm][0] = -1.0 / 2.0 * (r)+(dx / 2.0) + (i - 1.0) * dx;
                coords[numm][1] = -1.0 / 2.0 * (r)+(dx / 2.0) + (j - 1.0) * dx;
                coords[numm][2] = -1.0 / 2.0 * (r)+(dx / 2.0) + (k - 1.0) * dx;
                numm = numm + 1;


            }
        }
    }


}
```

pd.r is a double 0.005, dx is a double about 0.00026315, totnode is 6859.

I've tried two methods, the one that is there and the one commented out with //. Both give me the same error. I'm using visual studio 2019. I'm not so familiar with c and visual studio so forgive me if the question is silly. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: You never verify whether your memory allocation succeeded.

Comment: @Gerhardh sorry the exception gets thrown at the first for loop on this line     coords[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(double));

Comment: Please post all of your code. It should be compilable and runnable. As it is, there are too many values that are initialized outside of the code you've posted. Any one could have an issue. We can't help you with what we don't know about. You are accessing the array as if you used the first allocation method. To use the commented out one, a different access method would be required.

Comment: Sorry again the ndivx y and z are all 19

Comment: That means that `coords` is probably a `NULL` pointer. As I mentioned, you never check. I wonder why it fails. ~7,000*8 = 56kB isn't that large for `malloc` to fail.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by a null pointer? I've updated the code to include those other values

Comment: You might want to revisit the introductory chapters for pointers in you favorite C textbook. `NULL` is an invalid address. It is returned by `malloc` in case of an error. The error message indicates that you probably want to write to such an invalid address.

Comment: I've updated to code there and simplified it. It should be compilable now. All the info is there and ready to run @CraigEstey

Comment: Your error isn't a build error, it is an application run-time error. You can search with your error code and find a few microsoft docs that discuss it. I suspect you are iterating past your allocation bounds causing the exception somewhere or attempting to read/write in a block already freed, etc.. If you provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can compile and verify where the problem is. I'll see how close what you posted is.

Comment: If you compile that code, do you still get the error? I can't reproduce with that code.

Comment: You should run your code in the Debugger. Visual Studio should bring one.  There you should see where the error happens and can inspect values of your variables. Especially `coords` and `i` might be of interest.

Comment: So I've changed 2 things and it seems to work now. First I started debugging in x86. next I changed all the int's to double's 


 double** coords;
  coords = malloc(totnode * sizeof(double*));
  for (int i = 0; i < totnode; i++) {
   coords[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(double));

  }

Comment: I have no idea why this suddenly works

Comment: It runs fine with a few adjustments. (obviously this is taken from a larger block of code as your `(k = 0; k < ndivz; k++)` loop repeatedly overwrites the same values over and over again). But within these loops lies a ***landmine***. In C all arrays and blocks are zero indexed (e.g. for an `N -dim` array valid indexes are `0<= i < N`. However you choose your loop limits as `1 <= i <=N`. You appear to do this for your values in, e.g. `(i - 1.0)`. If you have no other code, that's OK, but if these index values are used elsewhere, problems can arise. Suggest `(i+1 - 1.0)` and loop `0 <= i < N`

Comment: So while what you show will work fine, I suspect you step on the ***landmine*** in other parts of your code you have not posted. (don't use **global** variables, they just lead to shadowing problems and name collisions in larger code) Declare all variable within `main()` and pass as parameters as needed. (there is a place for the use of global variables, but only in very limited circumstances not relevant here)

Comment: I have to define the loop from 1 in order for the equation for equal distance points in a cube to work. That's why I did the numm index so it saves in the coords from coords[0][0] and so on. 

If I use a loop again i do (int i = 0; i<whatever; i++) wont this reset the i ?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from some of the other errors [after correction], *all* values of `coords` are set to *zero*. This is because `coords` is a pointer to `int` and *not* (e.g.) `double` and your equation uses `-1.0 / ...` which will always produce a fraction.

Also, as David pointed out, you're indexing from 1 [vs. 0] in the `for` loops. This could cause access violations/segfaults.

I've changed the `for` loops to start from 0. And, I've adjusted the equation accordingly (using a macro).

You were defining some things like index variables or size variables as `double` instead of `int` (e.g.) `ndivx`

Also, I introduced a `typedef` for the coordinate values.

Here's some cleaned up code that may help get you further:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if 0
double ndivx, ndivy, ndivz, nt, r, box, dx, totnode;
#endif

#if 0
typedef int coord_t;
#else
typedef double coord_t;
#endif

#define SETCOORD(_xidx,_var) \
    do { \
        coords[numm][_xidx] = -1.0 / 2.0 * r + (dx / 2.0) + (_var * dx); \
        printf("coords[%d][%d]=%g\n",numm,_xidx,(double) coords[numm][_xidx]); \
    } while (0)

int
main(void)
{
#if 1
    int ndivx;
    int ndivy;
    int ndivz;
    double r;
    double dx;
#endif

    ndivx = 19;
    ndivy = 19;
    ndivz = 19;
    int totnode = ndivx * ndivy * ndivz;

    r = 0.005;                          // diameter of sphere
    dx = 0.0025 / ndivx;
#if 0
    double dx = r / ndivx;              // distance between points
#else
    dx = r / ndivx;             // distance between points
#endif

    int cols = 3;

#if 0
    int **coords;
#else
    coord_t **coords;
#endif

    coords = malloc(totnode * sizeof(coord_t *));
    for (int i = 0; i < totnode; i++) {
        coords[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(coord_t));
    }

    // int* coord = (int*)malloc(totnode * cols * sizeof(int));

    // int offset = i * cols + j;
    // now mat[offset] corresponds to m(i, j)
    // create a cube of equidistant points

    int numm = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ndivx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ndivy; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < ndivz; k++) {
                SETCOORD(0,i);
                SETCOORD(1,j);
                SETCOORD(2,k);
                numm = numm + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Craig I appreciate your time and effort